# What are the end of support dates for IE versions under Windows versions?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

All that I can find is tables that tell me that each recent Internet Explorer version's end of support date depends on its parent product. That doesn't help at all because you can have multiple IE versions on each Windows version.

I found a very good table sometime in the past that explained the exact end of support date for each IE version and OS version in combination. But I can't find it anymore. Does anybody know where it is?

Comment: From a quick search: http://inaneworld.com/2013/07/03/internet-explorer-end-of-life-lifecycle-dates/ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/30/730878.aspx http://routerconfigurationindia.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/support-lifecycle-of-internet-explorer.html

Comment: They're all incomplete. Especially IE8 on WinXP is missing everywhere.